# How to group by subitems of a list in a List?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala. I am curious about how to group sub-items of a list.

For example, I have data on categories of novels and their ratings. I want to get total ratings in a category.

Format of data: `(Option[List(categories)], Option[rating])`

```scala
var a = List(List(List("romance", "thriller"), 4), List(List("adventure", "thriller"), 3))
```

I want to get a mapping of Key(Category) => Value(Their ratings)

```scala
romance => (4,3)
thriller => (4,3)
adventure => (3)
```

I tried to do `a.groupby(_._1)`, but it only groups when they have the exact same categories. I tried to search other posts but couldn't find any similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first want to transform your data to a `List[(Category, Rating)]`, and then you can use `groupMap` to group by category.

```
val a = List(
  (List("romance", "thriller"), 4),
  (List("adventure", "thriller"), 3)
)

a.flatMap{ 
  case (cs, r) => cs.map(_ -> r)
}
.groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
```

Comment: Thank you. Please ignore my previous comment. Your code gave me the concept of how to manipulate this data structure and I got it to work for my case now

Answer (score 5):

This data structure is *extremely* hard to work with, and that might be a cause of your problems. You have a list, which in turn contains lists, each of which in turn contains two elements, the first of which is another list, and the second element is a number.

This has many, many problems. For starters, almost none of the lists actually *are* lists.

The innermost list is not a list, since the order of the elements doesn't matter. It should probably be a set.

The middle list is *very* problematic: since it contains both a list and a number, it cannot have a useful type. The best we can do is `List[Any]` in Scala 2 or `List[String | Integer]` in Scala 3. The actual type that is inferred in Scala 3 is `List[Matchable]`, which is essentially useless. It "pollutes" everything you try to do later. It should probably be a pair, i.e. a `(Set[String], Integer)`.

And the outer list doesn't actually need to be a list either, it can be any sequence; we don't particularly care what specific kind of sequence it is. All we care about is that we can iterate over it. In fact, it we don't care about the order, and we don't even care about sequentiality (it would work just fine to evaluate all elements in parallel), so arguably, the correct type would be just [`Iterable`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/trait-iterable.html).

So, let's fix that data structure first:

```scala
val ratings = Iterable(
  Set("romance", "thriller")   -> 4,
  Set("adventure", "thriller") -> 3
)
```

This data structure is both much easier to work with and more closely resembles the semantics of what you are trying to model.

In order to get the individual ratings for the genres, we need to flatten this representation out, so we get something like

```scala
Iterable(
  "romance"   -> 4,
  "thriller"  -> 4,
  "adventure" -> 3,
  "thriller"  -> 3
)
```

We can do this by `flatMap`ping over `ratings` and `map`ping each genre to a pair of (genre, rating):

```scala
val individualRatings = for
  (set, rating) <- ratings
  genre <- set
yield genre -> rating
```

Now, we can `groupBy` the genre, which will give us something like

```scala
Map(
  "romance"   -> ("romance"   -> Seq(4)),
  "thriller"  -> ("thriller"  -> Seq(4, 3)),
  "adventure" -> ("adventure" -> Seq(3))
)
```

Which means we need to `mapValues` to just their second element, so we end up with something like this:

```scala
Map(
  "romance"   -> Seq(4),
  "thriller"  -> Seq(4, 3),
  "adventure" -> Seq(3)
)
```

And lastly, we need to `reduce` the list of ratings to a single rating.

There is actually the helpful method [`Iterable.groupMapReduce`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html#groupMapReduce%5BK,B%5D(key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map%5BK,B%5D) which combines these three operations in an efficient manner:

```scala
val totals = individualRatings.groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(_ + _)
```

And the end result is this:

```scala
Map(
  "adventure" -> 3,
  "romance"   -> 4,
  "thriller"  -> 7
)
```

Note: even if you have no control over the data coming in, it still makes sense to "fix" the data as soon as it enters the system, and only ever work with the fixed data, instead of constantly having to deal with the broken data all the time.

You could, for example, create the data structure I outlined above from your data using something like this:

```scala
val ratings = for
  (genres: Iterable[String]) :: (rating: Int) :: Nil <- a
yield genres.toSet -> rating
```

Note that because of type erasure, this is actually not type-safe: at runtime, the element type of the `List` is erased, so it is impossible to know that the first element is a `List[String]` and the second element is an `Integer`. They are both treated as `Matchable`s, *even with* the type test in the pattern.
However, this is not necessarily the best we can do. Scala is an *object-oriented* programming language, after all, not a list-of-lists-of-lists-of-strings-or-numbers-oriented language.

What we have done, is we have improved the data structure from a list-of-lists-of-lists-of-strings-or-numbers to an iterable-of-pairs-of-sets-of-strings-and-numbers. What we would really like to have is an iterable-of-ratings.

I will leave that as an exercise for the reader for now.

Comment: This has been an interesting read and approach. I wouldn't have thought of manipulating the dataset to use Seq instead.

Comment: The `Seq` is the least interesting part. The most important is to use a strongly-typed structure, i.e. the `Tuple2[Set[String], Integer]` to represent the rating mapping instead of a practically untyped `List[Matchable]`.